# Getting distinct object from list in java

Tags: java

I have below table

```
question_text_id question_id language_id  question_text
2                    7           1         english_text_1
3                    7           2         spanish_text_1
4                    8           2         spanish_text_2
5                    8           1         english_text_2
```

NOw i want to create list for each distinct question_id

i have used below code

```
List<QuestionText> questionTextList = questionManager.getQuestionsTextByQuestionId(Long.parseLong(questions.getQuestionId().toString()));
for (QuestionText questionText : questionTextList) {
    questionMap.put("questionId", questionText.getQuestionId());
    questionMap.put("language", questionText.getLanguageId());
    if(questionText.getLanguageId().longValue() == 1){
        questionMap.put("englishQuestionText",questionText.getQuestionText());
    } else {
        questionMap.put("spanishQuestionText",questionText.getQuestionText());
    }
    questionListMap.add(questionMap);
}               
adminCollectionBookendModel.put("questionListMap",questionListMap);     

[{questionId = 1,language=1, englishQuestionText = english_text_1,spanishQuestionText=spanish_text_1},{questionId = 1,language=2, englishQuestionText = english_text_1,spanishQuestionText=spanish_text_1}]
```

But this give me repeatetion of object of same data if i have both spanish and english question text as shown above. How to get unique list?

**How to get both spanish text and english text for each question_id along with language_id and to access it?**

Please help me on this

Comment: Your `questionListMap` list contains the same object multiple times. Even if you create new maps at each iteration you won't get the expected results. What you'll need to do is to look through the list at each iteration to see if there is already a map in there for the current question and set its english or spanish text.

Comment: To add to the previous comment, you won't be able to add different values for `language` attribute in your map as it will be overridden. You might have to think of a different way to store this attribute if you want the languageIds for both the languages along with their texts.

Comment: @user2004685 Other work around is also good, Please tell me how to achieve my requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step would be to create a POJO Class like this,

```
public class QuestionDetails {

    private int questionId;
    private int englishLanguageId;
    private int spanishLanguageId;
    private String englishLanguageText;
    private String spanishLanguageText;

    public int getQuestionId() {
        return questionId;
    }

    public void setQuestionId(int questionId) {
        this.questionId = questionId;
    }

    public int getEnglishLanguageId() {
        return englishLanguageId;
    }

    public void setEnglishLanguageId(int englishLanguageId) {
        this.englishLanguageId = englishLanguageId;
    }

    public int getSpanishLanguageId() {
        return spanishLanguageId;
    }

    public void setSpanishLanguageId(int spanishLanguageId) {
        this.spanishLanguageId = spanishLanguageId;
    }

    public String getEnglishLanguageText() {
        return englishLanguageText;
    }

    public void setEnglishLanguageText(String englishLanguageText) {
        this.englishLanguageText = englishLanguageText;
    }

    public String getSpanishLanguageText() {
        return spanishLanguageText;
    }

    public void setSpanishLanguageText(String spanishLanguageText) {
        this.spanishLanguageText = spanishLanguageText;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new StringBuilder().append("questionId: ").append(questionId)
                .append(" ,englishLanguageId: ").append(englishLanguageId)
                .append(" ,englishLanguageText: ").append(englishLanguageText)
                .append(" ,spanishLanguageId: ").append(spanishLanguageId)
                .append(" ,spanishLanguageText: ").append(spanishLanguageText)
                .toString();
    }
}
```

Next step would be to change your code snippet like this:

```
List<QuestionDetails> questionsList = new ArrayList<>();
List<QuestionText> questionTextList = questionManager
        .getQuestionsTextByQuestionId(Long.parseLong(questions
                .getQuestionId().toString()));
for (QuestionText questionText : questionTextList) {
    /* Get QuestionDetails Object */
    QuestionDetails qd = getQuestionDetails(
            questionText.getQuestionId(), questionsList);
    /* Check Null */
    if(null == qd) {
        /* Get New Object */
        qd = new QuestionDetails();
        /* Add Object To List */
        questionsList.add(qd);
    }
    /* Set Question ID */
    qd.setQuestionId(questionText.getQuestionId());
    /* Set Language ID & Text */
    if (questionText.getLanguageId().longValue() == 1) {
        qd.setEnglishLanguageId(questionText.getLanguageId()
                .longValue());
        qd.setEnglishLanguageText(questionText.getQuestionText());
    } else {
        qd.setSpanishLanguageId(questionText.getLanguageId()
                .longValue());
        qd.setSpanishLanguageText(questionText.getQuestionText());
    }
}
adminCollectionBookendModel.put("questionListMap", questionsList);
```

Finally, here is the implementation of the `getQuestionDetails` function:

```
private QuestionDetails getQuestionDetails(int questionId,
        List<QuestionDetails> questionsList) {
    /* Search Existing Object */
    for (QuestionDetails qd : questionsList) {
        /* Match Found */
        if (qd.getQuestionId() == questionId) {
            return qd;
        }
    }

    /* No Object Found */
    return null;
}
```

Comment: This is giving me same object repeated 5 times

Comment: @allDroid Updated the solution. It should work fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend doing the following:

To distinguish `QuestionText`, you need to override `equals` method using `question_text_id`. Otherwise two questions with the same `question_id`, but different language texts would be equal.

Then create two separate maps for each language. Then just iterate throug all questions and put each question in a corresponding map by `question_id`. You can retrive a question object by its `question_id` and get all necessary fields from it, including spanish / english text

```
List<QuestionText> questionTextList = questionManager.getQuestionsTextByQuestionId(Long.parseLong(questions.getQuestionTextId().toString()));
for (QuestionText questionText : questionTextList) {

    if(questionText.getLanguageId().longValue() == 1){
        englishQuestionMap.put("question_id",questionText);
    } else {
        spanishQuestionMap.put("question_id",questionText);
    }
    questionListMap.add(questionMap);
}
```

So, your maps will have type of `Map<Long, QuestionText>`